# Plotting data from a tapply output in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, plot, tapply

I'm a real beginner and trying to analyze some data on the material loss on some metal tubes for my master thesis. I want to compare the standard deviation of the material loss over an interval for different tubes. I created some sub matrices and did a `tapply` to calculate the standard deviation.

I have the following script:

```
myfunctionSD <- function(mydata) { return(sd(mydata,na.rm=TRUE))}

Alltubes <- tapply(datIn$Material.loss.interval,
                   list(as.factor(datIn$Measurement.location),
                        as.factor(datIn$Tube.number)),
                   myfunctionSD)
```

of which the output is a table with on column header the `Tube.number` and the row title `Measurement.location`.

```
dput(head(Alltubes))

structure(c(0.871073958553372, NA, 0.697795091282526, NA, 0.838624866472886, 
NA, 0.726992791242471, 0.807567484588899, NA, 0.598675787394729, 
NA, 0.510990323891863, 0.81510216193526, NA, 1.09844645540173, 
NA, 0.839816448199645, NA, 0.63972340253115, NA, 1.11485875917537, 
NA, 0.883318358663128, NA, 0.86706340125676, NA, 1.21565055332783, 
NA, 1.24692213662875, NA, 0.704210691776757, NA, 0.962002980998362, 
NA, 1.00703215272093, NA), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
    "5", "6")))
```

Just to be clear: the 1,2,3,4,5,6 are the tube numbers and header of the columns and the 1, 10, 11...are the measurement locations and header of the rows.

I would like to make different plots of the data, one of them is:
Boxplot with on the x-axis the tube number and the y-axis the spread of the derived standard deviation.

I have searched everywhere and have tried lots of different things, but I cant get a graph to appear.

Hope someone can help me, will be much appreciated!

Comment: Show us how the data looks: `dput(head(Alltubes))`. Then we may be able to help you.

Comment: Shadow, I just edited the original message, hope this is a bit clear for you? There isnt always a calculated value for each measurement location, thus the many NA's

Comment: Thanks for providing data. Is `boxplot(Alltubes)` what you are looking for?

Comment: Wauw I tried about every difficult plot function and forgot to use the easiest way.... It is what is was looking for. Do you also know a quick one to instead of showing it as function of the column headers, as function of the row headers (Measurement.location). Thanks anyway, still cant believe it works!

Comment: and a line plot of the different tubes with on the x-axis the measurement location and the y axis the standard deviation. So in total 6 lines (one for each tube)

Comment: To get by rows wouldn't it just be boxplot( t(Alldata))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a special function to do what you want, you can pass `na.rm=TRUE` to `tapply`:

```
Alltubes <- tapply(datIn$Material.loss.interval,
                   list(as.factor(datIn$Measurement.location),
                        as.factor(datIn$Tube.number)),
                   sd, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Then you can use:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(4,4,1,1), oma=c(1,1,1,1))

boxplot(Alltubes, names=colnames(Alltubes), xlab="Tube numbers",
        ylab="standard deviation")

boxplot(t(Alltubes), names=rownames(Alltubes), 
        xlab="Measurement locations", ylab="standard deviation")

matplot(colnames(Alltubes), t(Alltubes), xlab="Tube numbers", 
        ylab="standard deviation", type="b", lty=1, pch=19)

matplot(rownames(Alltubes), Alltubes, xlab="Measurement locations", 
        ylab="standard deviation", type="b", lty=1, pch=19)
```

[image: theplot]